# Scheme check value if not even

Tags: scheme, logical-operators

I have the following function to check if a positive value is even.

```
(define (even? n)
    (cond
        ((= n 0) #t)
        ((< n 0) #f)
        (else (even? (- n 2)))
    )
)
```

I am trying to use this function to increment a store counter when a checked value is not even (odd) using both the `even?` function and a logical `not`, but I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax.

```
(define (function a b)
    (define (iter a b store)
        (cond
            ((= b 1) (+ store a)
            (else
                (iter (double a) (halve b) (if (not (even? b)) (+ a store) store)))
            )
        )
    (iter a b 0)
)
```

Could anyone check my syntax to see what I am doing wrong?

A call of `(function 1 1)` should return 1

A call of `(fucntion 1960 56)` should return 109760 but I receive 141120

EDIT:
I realize that my `halve` funciton must be impromperly defined. I tried to implement a halving function that used only subtraction.

```
(define (halve n)
    (define (iter src store)
        (cond
            ((<= src 0) store)
            (else (iter (- src 2) (+ store 1)))
            )
        )
    (iter n 0)
    )
```

Comment: Your first case in `iter` returns `store` if `b` is 1 (which, in your example, it is), so it returns 0; you're not even getting to the use of `even?`.

Comment: @ScottHunter I updated the base case, becauase you were right. I still receive issues with larger numbers though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the `even?` function is built-in, you don't have to implement it. Now regarding the problem - this line is not doing what you think:

```
(if (not (even? b)) (+ a store))
```

That expression doesn't update the value of `store`, it's just evaluating the result of adding `a` to `store` and then the value obtained is lost - we didn't save it, we didn't pass it to the recursion, the result of the addition is discarded and then the next line is executed.

In Scheme, we use `set!` to update a variable, but that's frowned upon, we try to avoid mutation operations - and in this case it's not necessary, we only need to pass the correct value to the recursive call.

**UPDATE**

Now that you've made it clear that you're implementing the [Ethiopian multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication) algorithm, this is how it should be done:

```
(define (halve n)
  (quotient n 2))

(define (double n)
  (* 2 n))

(define (function a b)
  (define (iter a b store)
    (cond
      ((= a 0) store)
      ((even? a) (iter (halve a) (double b) store))
      (else (iter (halve a) (double b) (+ store b)))))
  (iter a b 0))
```

It works as expected:

```
(function 1 1)
=> 1
(function 1960 56)
=> 109760
```

Comment: This is better. The base case now works as expected, but for the second case I'm still not returning the correct number.

Comment: @user3277752 it'll be a lot easier if you tell us the actual name and definition of the function, it can't be called just "function". Also, please don't update the question with our solutions, it'll invalidate previous answers

Comment: I'm trying to implement Ethiopian multiplication. As I type this I realized that my `halve` function must be the issue.

Comment: @user3277752 you should have mentioned that from the beginning. Anyway, my last update contains the correct implementation.

Comment: How can you implement the `halve` function using only subtraction?

Comment: @user3277752 all right. so we can close this question already: in your `halve` procedure, change this: `(<= src 0)` to this: `(<= src 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing a `)`, just before the call to `iter`.

Comment: It should be correct now I think, but I don't think that is the reason for it not working.